# javascript object not working inside fetch

Tags: javascript, redux

```
function uiReducer(state = {
  authenticated: savedState ? savedState.uiState.authenticated : false,
  infoDialogVisible: false
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'LOGIN': 
      const url = 'http://localhost/api/api.php';
      fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(function(data) 
      {

        let info = data.results;
        if(info.auth === true) { alert("fdg");  Object.assign({}, state, {authenticated: true});  }

      })
```

Saved state code: ######

```
let savedState = localStorage.getItem('AuthManagerState');
if (savedState) {
  savedState = JSON.parse(savedState);
}
```

The above code is just to set the login mode to true but it doesn't work and when I debugged I realised 'authenticated' is not defined or something so can someone point out what I'm doing wrong as I got no idea and I'm new to this javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, state, {authenticated: true});` does nothing by the way - as you are creating a new object `{}` and assigning to it, then ignoring the result - if you want to add authenticated to state using Object.assign - `Object.assign(state, {authenticated: true})` ... though, why not just `state.authenticated = true`

Comment: @JaromandaX You should not do ```Object.assign(state, ...)``` in redux, that transforms an existing object. Instead, Object.assign({}, state, ...) copies state to a new object.

Comment: Fair enough @ChristopherMeyers, as there was no `return` I assumed the intent was to change `state`

Comment: I think the issue is something related fetch thing as the code of authenticate value set to true perfectly outside the fetch function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really enough code to understand what's going on.

1. You'd need to include what savedState is. According to this code, it doesn't exist.
2. If you are seeing something about 'authenticated' being undefined its likely because savedState.uiState is undefined and you are trying to access uiState.authenticated.

You may have to do this:

```
(savedState && savedState.uiState && savedState.uiState.authenticated) || false
```

OR this could work

```
!!(savedState && savedState.uiState && savedState.uiState.authenticated)
```

You will also want to use the Object.assign value with a ***return***, like this:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {authenticated: true});
```

The bigger issue is that the reducer can't wait for fetch to complete before returning, so its returning nothing. You will need something outside of this reducer (a click handler, for example) to complete the fetch, and then dispatch the LOGIN action from that, something like this:

```
handleClick = () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost/api/api.php';
  fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let info = data.results;
      if(info.auth === true) {
        alert("fdg"); 
        this.props.dispatchLoginAction({
          type: 'LOGIN'
        })
      }
    })
}
```

then your reducer can look like this:

```
function uiReducer(state = {
  authenticated: savedState ? savedState.uiState.authenticated : false,
  infoDialogVisible: false
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {authenticated: true});
  }
}
```

You will need to use redux bindActionCreators and dispatch to construct the dispatchLoginAction function, if you don't understand how to do those, you'll need to read about them in the redux documentation.

Comment: Add the savedstate in question now. please kindly recheck.

Comment: After alert i missed return code.

Basically it's return Object.assign({}, state, {authenticated: true});

Comment: @MegRay I updated my response to show an example of how you can have an async action (ie fetch) that updates the state in a reducer.

Answer (score 2):

What your code does is to update a reducer based on response from fetch. Unfortunately, the code will never work.

Redux's reducer is simply a Javascript function, which means it takes inputs in (`state` & `action`), computes and returns new state value immediately. It does not wait for any asynchronous process, and in your case, it is the fetch call. So no matter what you do, you cannot force your `uiReducer` to wait until fetch's response come and update at that time. The reducer does not work that way.

You need to read the original document from Redux about [handling async actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions), and probably need to consider using supporting library for async actions for redux, such as redux-thunk, redux-promise or redux-saga.

Comment: So what is possible solution to this?

Comment: Please read the above link first to understand async flow in redux. Then move the fetch call out of your `uiReducer` and use either one of the libraries I suggested to handle the call and returns response to reducer.

Comment: Can you please give a small example of how it should be put in place?

Answer (score -1):

The second then should be for the res.json(). Do not close the brace there.

```
function uiReducer(state = {
 authenticated: savedState ? savedState.uiState.authenticated : false,
 infoDialogVisible: false
}, action) {
switch (action.type) {

case 'LOGIN': 
  const url = 'http://localhost/api/api.php';
  fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json().then(function(data) 
  {

    let info = data.results;
    if(info.auth === true) { alert("fdg");  Object.assign({}, state, {authenticated: true});  }

  })
```

Also I am not sure where the `savedState` in this line is coming from. 
`authenticated: savedState ? savedState.uiState.authenticated : false,`

Comment: why are you nesting `.then`? Clearly you do not understand Promise chaining. *This code has **no** discernible difference to code in question!*

Comment: Kindly look carefully at the code. The second then is the promise handler for the res.json().

Comment: Kindly look at every sample usage of `fetch`, and how Promises allow you to avoid such `nesting` - your code is no better (in fact worse) than the original code - also, you failed at adding code to your answer ... some of it is not in a "code block"